# How to download this library from Github

Tags: github, arduino, github-pages, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

In this repository I could't find any download button(clone download). But I have founded these kind of repositories without clone download button. can anybody please help me out how to download these kind of libraries.

link is here:[https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/tree/master/Arduino/I2Cdev]

Comment: What can't you do? The Github has always a download button. You have to download the repository. And once downloaded you have to copy the library in your Arduino library folder (this is the second question, right?). But why download this library and not one that is available through your Arduino IDE?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to clone the repo via [Git](https://git-scm.com/) (make sure it's installed, if not, download it [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads)) as an alternative method to download the library.

Once git is installed, open up a terminal, and enter this command to clone the repository:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib.git
```